# Moving elements from a list to another list with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I would like to add an element to another list and remove it from the current when clicked. I tried it with the property appendTo of Selectable, but nothing happens when I click on it.

I built this https://jsfiddle.net/wgaga8uc/ to ilustrate it.

```
 $("#paramselectable").selectable({appendTo: "#paramselected"});
 $("#paramselected").selectable({appendTo: "#paramselectable"});
```

I would appreciate any help,
Thanks.

Comment: You may need sortable instead of selectable, something like http://jsfiddle.net/r83zY/134/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I achieved it adding and removing classes.  https://jsfiddle.net/22d7sxvd/

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".paramsnav" ).selectable();
  });

 $('li').click(function () {
     var selected = $('#params').find('.ui-selected');
     if(selected.hasClass('selectable')) {
         selected.removeClass('ui-selected');
         selected.removeClass('selectable');
         selected.addClass('selected');
         selected.appendTo('#paramselected');
     } else {
         selected.removeClass('ui-selected');
         selected.removeClass('selected');
         selected.addClass('selectable');
         selected.appendTo('#paramselectable');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#paramselected li").click(function(){
 $("#paramselectable").append(document.createTextNode( "Hello" ));
});
```

Comment: I don not want to create a new node, I would like to move the current.